# Android application connected to an ActiveMQ server

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, message

I wanted to know if it is possible to create an Android Application that sends and receives messages through the ActiveMQ server? if its been done can you show me some examples perhaps?

Thank you for taking the time to read

Answer (score 1):

you can use Stomp Java lib to consume from queues https://github.com/fusesource/stompjms

here an example of android app that talk to activemq https://github.com/jsherman1/android-mqtt-demo

https://dzone.com/articles/android-mqtt-activemq

http://activemq.apache.org/mqtt.html

> ActiveMQ supports the MQTT protocol and will automatically map between
>   JMS/NMS and MQTT clients. MQTT is a machine-to-machine (M2M)
>   publish/subscribe messaging transport.

Comment: Thank you hassen, really useful to awnser

Comment: It's a good starting point to try something. I tried to help you as i can.