# Android: connect to ActiveMQ

Tags: android, jms, activemq-classic

I am a total newbie to Android and I'm having trouble with writing an app which connects to ActiveMQ to send message to a queue and later get it from there. What tools or libraries to use? Can it be implemented in the way like in simple java jms api? Kind like that http://activemq.apache.org/hello-world.html

I cannot find any accessible example or explanation. All available info on that is simply impossible for me to grasp. 
Would be veeeery thankful for any explanation (examples will be highly appreciated ).

Comment: you can at least try using that `ActiveMQConnectionFactory` and other classes, and see if it works by yourself.

Comment: Take a look here to find some examples to start with  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42576046/android-application-connected-to-an-activemq-server/42576509#42576509

Comment: Can I use Kaazing Android jms client api?